# One always tells truth and the other lies, figure which is which in only n tries

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Here's a simpler and finalized version of the puzzle, the previous got messy due to its WIP status.

---

Enter the hall of the twin oracles.

One of the oracles is true, and its purpose is to always tell the truth.

The other oracle is false, and its purpose is to always hide its falsehood.

Both oracles know everything, and answer valid questions with yes or no only.

Both oracles don't answer questions which are invalid or defy their purpose.

Your quest is to figure which is which in the least amount of questions possible.

---

Disclaimer:

*The puzzle is being reverse engineered for a specific requested outcome. So pardon its early immaturity, may you find the maturity to realize that it is an incremental process that requires diversity of input.*

Big fat hint:

> The solution state involves a valid question which the false oracle cannot neither copy nor reverse the answer of without defying its purpose, so ultimately and inevitably it is cornered into compromising itself by not giving an answer that would compromise it.

Comment: Doesn't the edit just make this unsolvable? If there were any set of questions where the lying oracle's answers differ from the truthful one we would be able to differentiate the two, so wouldn't the lying oracle just give the same answers as the truthful one all the time making it impossible to differentiate the two?

Comment: @GoblinGuide it is solvable, I will post my solution eventually but I am curious as to what other people will think of.

Comment: I agree with @GoblinGuide. The lying oracle is allowed to give the exact same answers that the truth teller would every single time, in which case there is no possible means of distinguishing the two - if you swap the two oracles, you get the same set of answers but the opposite conclusion about who is the liar.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie your appear frustrated, there is a solution to the puzzle, you just haven't figured it out yet. Would you like another hint?

Comment: I would suggest simplifying the way you ask the question. It seems to have a lot of rules and words that cloud what you are looking for, and make it harder to discern. It seems like a great question, if perhaps written differently.

Comment: In light of the most recent disclaimer, would you be willing to simply share your intended solution and have the question be us helping you define a question that makes that solution the only answer? It could work similarly to a 'sandbox' from the code-golf forum, if you are familiar.

Comment: @J.Dingo well, it is for a somewhat commercial / charity fundraiser production purpose, so revealing it is a potential leak and total spoiler to share it before the event is completed. It is actually a good thing it still remains elusive now that the conditions are all straightened up, and despite the dropped hints.

Comment: I understand. In that case, could you please clarify the rules for the deceitful (false) oracle? As-is, both Nuclear Hoagie and I have submitted proofs that with the rules the way they are, there is no solution.

Comment: @J.Dingo again, to clarify it that much would essentially involve giving up the solution. There is one single scenario in which the false oracle is in a dead lock, where it can't copy the true oracle's answer or provide the opposite answer without defying its purpose, thus remain silent on a valid question, thus indicating it can't answer it without defying its purpose. The solution state is when the true oracle answers the truth and the false oracle answers nothing.

Comment: Well, the one solution state I know anyway, there might be more.

Comment: We may be misunderstanding what you mean by "defying its purpose", then. I was under the assumption the deceitful oracle basically operated as follows: 1. Obligated to tell you false information, except... 2. If an answer could be used to identify which oracle they are, they can answer any way they like, and finally 3. if the honest oracle would see a question as invalid, they can choose to see it as invalid too.

Comment: If the liar failing to copy the true oracle's answer gives away the liar, *then the liar can't do that*. Whatever the truth teller answered can't possibly mark the truth teller as the liar, because he's *not* the liar. The liar should just copy that answer and not give himself away.

Comment: The liar can't copy an answer that compromises its ability to lie, cuz then it wouldn't be a lie.

Comment: Are you saying the liar can't tell the truth?

Comment: I guess that's where I think the current wording falls short. I don't read this as the Liar being forced to give a false answer, ever, merely that they are obligated to hide the fact that they could give a false answer.

Comment: Go back and read the question body carefully. There is no liar - the false oracle's purpose is to keep its falsehood hidden. It can use truth, lie or silence for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one step:

> "If I asked the other Oracle if he's a liar, what would he say?"

> The truth-teller must truthfully tell you the liar would (falsely) answer "no". The liar must (falsely) tell you the truth-teller would answer "yes".

Alternatively, you could ask:

> "Is the answer to this question no?"

> The truth-teller has no valid answer - answering yes means the answer is not no, but answering no means the answer is no. Any answer is a lie - if the person you ask responds with either a yes or a no, they are a liar.

EDIT:

> The question now has no solution. By definition, the liar must conceal their identity and cannot make any statement that will allow you to determine they are the liar. If at any point you figure out who the liar is, the liar must have made, or have been accurately predicted to make, a statement that revealed their identity, which is expressly not allowed. The truth teller has exactly zero alternatives of what to say, since they are bound by the truth - that means it must be *the liar's own misstep* that gets him caught. Had he simply not done whatever it was that let you figure it out, he'd have been fine. Any "solution" can be nullified by recognizing that whatever the "final question" was that gave you the solution, the liar could have just *answered differently*.

Comment: I like the alternative, since I think it must be more like what the OP is going for, as "I'm confused" doesn't seem like something a deceitful person would say. Otherwise, the "one step" solution is effectively the same as my answer, but phrased as a single question.

Comment: @MichaelFoster It's not the same -  you need to get one oracle to reference the other in order to get a lie about a truth or a truth about a lie, which is always a lie either way.  It allows you to know that whatever the answer is, it's false. Your solution of asking one oracle questions about themselves doesn't work.

Comment: Both of those involve the deceitful oracle compromising itself, therefore failing to serve its obligatory purpose. In both cases, it is under no obligation to compromise itself, and it can give you the exact same answer as the truthful oracle in order to facilitate its innate deception.

Comment: Neither oracles have a valid answer for a logically invalid question because the question is technically unspecified, which is undefined behavior, and in practice, the question happens to be a self-reference, which leads to infinite logical recursion, therefore neither of the oracles answer. You broke both oracles and can no longer hope to learn the truth. Just kidding, keep them coming if you got them.

Comment: @dtech This seems unsolvable then. You're saying that by definition, the liar will never say anything that reveals themselves. It's possible that the liar tells the truth in response to every single question, in which case their behavior is absolutely indistinguishable from the truth-teller. I don't see how you can do anything useful when both people respond exactly the same. If you claim person A is the liar, I can conclude person B is the liar based on the exact same reasoning, since they gave the same answers.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie the false oracle's ultimate purpose is to deceive you. It breaks when it fails to meet that condition. If it trips itself over an undefined question, it wouldn't be much of a deceiver, don't you think?

Comment: @dtech If the liar trips over the undefined question and the truth-teller doesn't, they have given themselves away and should instead have simply said whatever the truth-teller would have said.  If the truth-teller gives the same response to the undefined question, the response gives no information whatsoever.

Comment: An undefined question is not a valid question. The oracles answer questions. Not non-questions.

Comment: The answer is at the same time both logically simpler and conceptually more challenging than you anticipate. That's my final hint, just for you.

Answer (score 3):

> Ask both oracles "Does the answer dtech has in mind begin with an a? Does it begin with a b?" etc until you have the first letter of the answer according to each oracle. Then do the same for the 2nd letter, 3rd letter, etc. Eventually one of the two oracles (the truthful one) will have spelled out the method that dtech has in mind for figuring out which oracle is truthful. Then employ the method.

Comment: Gotta LOL about it, the closest thing to a working answer, and its dull brute forge guessing. Slow clap.

Comment: The key question can be formulated in multitude different ways, so as this is, the true oracle can just give you a letter of a different yet valid formulation every time, so you end up with random garbage. You could explicitly specify a single formulation of the key question and that would work theoretically. In practice the number of questions will be limited, so as to not defeat the purpose of playing it. But even if you manage to fit in the limit, taking so many steps to solve it will dilute your end score, thus you never enter the Hall of Champions, where only the sharpest of wit can enter

Comment: Ultimately, having obtained the answer by brutish force and cutting corners doesn't carry the insight of figuring it out. You are thus unable to obtain the wisdom of the oracle, and only managed to foolheadedly succeed at defeating your own purpose to obtain it. Having taken the lesson for granted now prevents you from learning its essence. But you can't even figure that much out, as in the place of the power of wisdom you proudly carry the burden of bare pride. You did figure it out after all. You have beaten the game by beating yourself to your victory.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is

> Will your answer to the following question be positive?

Your second question is

> Was your answer to the previous question negative?

Both oracles

> know what you're going to ask (they're oracles after all), and that the two questions lead to a logical paradox. So you break the truthful oracle. But the deceitful oracle isn't broken, because it can answer both questions by lying at least once. So whichever one still works is the deceitful oracle.

Comment: There's two issues with this. The first is that in neither of the two questions ask a concrete  / defined question. In that case, both oracles will give you an undefined / NA answer. But even if that was not the case, you are immediately trapped in an infinite curricular reference.

Comment: I don't think I understand your objections. In what sense is each question not "concrete/defined"? They have unambiguously correct and incorrect potential answers (at least in isolation). And what's a "curricular reference", and how would a question "trap" someone? And who is trapped?

Comment: Circular reference is when you have two values that depend on each other. That's what traps the flow of your logic in an infinite loop. And in your case that a circular reference between two undefined values.

Comment: @dtech It's not clear what you mean by "infinite loop". No computers are involved here.

Comment: It is basic universal logic. The same concept can be expressed as a flow chart. Flow chars are not computers, but permit infinite loops under the requisite conditions.

Comment: Ah, but that isn’t how oracles work. It can’t be, because by the Incompleteness Theorem no process equivalent to classic computation can correctly/truthfully state that any true statement is true. In any case, the fact remains that the deceitful oracle *can* answer those questions, by lying. No loops necessary.

Comment: If an oracle's answers do not abide to basic universal logic, you can't make anything out of them to begin with. No oracle can answer a non-question, because a non-question is not a question. And in any case, even if you non-question was a question, and there wasn't a circular reference, the false oracle can simply answer the same way as the true oracle. Thus your solution is invalid even if we generously overlook its logical errors.

Comment: Ah, but the true oracle cannot answer, because for them there is an actual logical paradox. As you’ve already said in a comment on another answer, an oracle which can’t answer without creating a logical paradox “breaks”. Here that only applies to one. The deceitful oracle cannot break because nothing has caused it to break.

Comment: But yes, yes it was a question. That’s what a question is. When you ask about something.

Comment: I get what you are saying. The true oracle cannot give you a true answer, because both "yes, no" and "no, yes" sequences will be just as true, and by extension, just as false. Knowing your second question in advance, both oracles remain silent after the first one, and there's no way to tell which is which. The false oracle is under no obligation to give you a true or false answer, just to conceal its falsehood from you.

Comment: That conflicts with the information you you gave earlier  that an oracle “breaks” when it cannot answer. (It also conflicts with your previous objection. I’m starting to think that your real objection here is “It wasn’t the answer I was thinking of”.)

Answer (score 2):

> One oracle is always truthful, and the other - always deceitful. Based on inquiry in that limited context, is it logically possible to determine which is which in any number of steps?

> And because it is an oracle, it knows everything that you know and don't know, hence it has a full proof way to establish when it needs to tell the truth so it can position you for the deceitful strike.

With these two together, I think the answer is simply

> No, it's not possible

Proof:

> The deceitful oracle knows everything you know, including what questions you intend to ask. They also know the other oracle is the truth-teller, and thus what it will respond to any question. They can prevent you from ever finding out which is which by simply copying what the honest oracle's response would be to any given question.

> Suppose there was a series of questions and answers that would identify the deceitful oracle as deceitful. By necessity, at some point in that exchange, the deceitful oracle's answer must differ from the honest oracle's. The deceitful oracle knows they will be identified ahead of time by this series of questions, and thus can avoid being identified by answering the same as the honest oracle, as it is necessary to deceive you. Thus the deceitful oracle will never give an answer that can possibly be used to identify it as deceitful.

However:

> There's an implication here that the real **goal** of determining which oracle is honest is to ask it some oracle-tier question about life, the universe, whatever. If this is really the goal, you can achieve it by simply asking the question to both. If you get the same answer from both, then you know you got honest information. If you get a different answer from each, we have actually have something to work with here and can start differentiating the two. *I strongly suspect that any lie at all can be used to differentiate one oracle from another. I am not at all convinced it is even possible for the deceitful oracle to lie to you.* However, the question *as asked* about if we are able to tell one from another, I believe, is simply answered "no".

EDIT:

> With all the clarifications and hints, it seems like the bit we are meant to focus on is:
>  > its purpose is to always hide its falsehood.
>  The wording here seems very precise. It's not meant simply to tell falsehoods, but to hide its status, and could potentially tell falsehoods in pursuit of that.
>  With that in mind, is the solution something along the lines of:
>  Ask the oracle, "Would the other oracle say that you are the liar?"
>  To my mind, this should simply elicit a "Yes" from both, but maybe you're trying to say that the false oracle can't answer this kind of question, as it is admitting that the other oracle would see it as false?

Comment: Figuring out which oracle is which grants you the Touch of Profound Wisdom skill, which enables you to know everything. The oracles are limited to yes and no answers.

Comment: Your comment seems directed at the last paragraph, but that is more of an addendum speculating on the question rather than a substantial part of the actual answer. Have I overlooked something in my proof?

Comment: The main problem with your proof is it attempts to prove the wrong premise. It is possible to guess which is which in only n tries.

Comment: That's not how proofs work, but I'll bite - what stops the deceitful oracle from answering questions identically to the honest oracle for all `n` responses? If its goal is to remain hidden it can simply mimic the honest oracle's responses exactly, leaving no way to discern which is which. Is one of my assumptions wrong? Can the oracle not always know what the honest one would say and then say it?

Comment: Obviously, the false oracle cannot copy a true answer that defies its purpose of falsehood. I am pretty much spelling it for you at this point...

Comment: I think the question might be helped by a more complete explanation of the deceitful oracle. "Obviously, the false oracle cannot copy a true answer that defies its purpose of falsehood" contradicts your comment on @Nuclear Hoagie's answer: "In both cases, it is under no obligation to compromise itself, and it can give you the exact same answer as the truthful oracle in order to facilitate its innate deception"

Comment: I can't give you an example that is not the answer to the puzzle. If properly designed, there should be only one logical exception that puts the false oracle in a logical dead lock.

Comment: I understand that a counterexample would give away the solution. It seems from the most recent disclaimer edit that the goal here is to revise the question until there is only one proper solution. Would you be willing to share the answer so we could help find the right wording of the question? I don't think stackexchange is a good place for a dialogue taking place via editting back and forth. In absence of that, would you be willing to clarify exactly how the deceitful oracle's logic works?

Comment: The false oracle cannot admit to being false. It doesn't expose the false oracle if it admits the true oracle says the truth about it being false, because you haven't established that it is the true oracle. The false oracle can tell you that the true oracle would call it false so long as you don't know which is which. The false oracle will answer differently depending on whether you know or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it in two questions, I believe:

> Do you answer questions deceitfully?

and then

> Was your answer to my previous question to you deceitful?

Explanation:

> Both will answer the first question with "no", since the false Oracle wants to deceive. Then the second question effectively forces truth, by making the false Oracle answer "yes", so the answer is the opposite of the answer given.

As far as I can see, this complies with the requirements. I don't otherwise have any idea what you're looking for.

Comment: Math is "outside the set context", and it would constitute a third leverage point in a context that only has the two.

Comment: One need not use math, but any true statement. Math is unambiguous, but lots of other things are also unambiguous. I'll add one such with an additional spoiler tag.

Comment: I seem to not have worded it correctly in the original question. By "always lies" I mean the lying oracle is under obligation to always deceive you, not under obligation to flip the logical truth, which wouldn't be all that useful means of deception. I will try to reword the question to emphasize on that.

Comment: I have an idea, but will wait for the edited question to see if it applies. I'm unsure what conditions will make it work.

Comment: When asking the liar the second question, an answer of "yes" would be truthfully stating that they lied the first time. They must answer "no", falsely claiming that they did not lie the first time. The answer to both questions should be "no" regardless of who you ask.

Comment: The false oracle can't tell you that it is false, and it will match the truthful oracle's answer in order to deceive you away from figuring it out.